# Не срабатывает условный оператор else в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий нерабочий код

```js
if ($('.block1').hasClass('plus')) {
    $('.block2').click(function () {
    $('.block1').addClass('lolo');
    });
} 
else ($('.block1').hasClass('lolo')) {
     $('.block2').click(function () {
    $('.block1').removeClass('lolo');
    })
}
```

```css
.block1 {
  background:red;
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
}
.block2 {
  background:green;
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
}
.lolo {
  height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class='block1 plus'></div>
```

При этом если удалить else, то код работает.

```
if ($('.block1').hasClass('plus')) {
    $('.block2').click(function () {
    $('.block1').addClass('lolo');
    });
}
```

Где здесь ошибка?

Приклике на зелёный квадрат высота карсного должна менять с помощтью добавления класса, при втором клике класс должен удаляться. 
Интересует именно как можно выполнить это с помощью операторов в jquery без использования .toggleClasse

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkTok/tr0377a5/

Comment: Должно быть либо `else {}`, либо `else if () {}`. В вашем случает нужно убрать второе условие и оставить только `else {}`

Comment: @Cheg увы, это не решает проблему

Comment: Добавьте фрагменты html и css для воспроизведения проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('.block2').click(function () {
    var block1 = $('.block1');
    if (block1.hasClass('lolo')) {
        block1.removeClass('lolo');
    } else {
        block1.addClass('lolo');
    }
});
```

Этот код задаёт обработчик click один раз и уже внутри обработчика происходит анализ что делать в момент клика

Comment: Спасибо за решение!!